# Are Muslims allowed to talk while eating?

Tags: fiqh, reference-request, adab

Assalaamu Alaikum,

I recently had a discussion/argument with my bud regarding this. According to his Aalim Muslims should talk a bit while eating because Yahoodi(Jews) do not talk while eating so as part of Muqalifat(in offense) Muslims should talk?

He didn't prove this by any evidence which I asked for but still the question arises, if an Aalim has commented on this.

So if anybody has any reference to this or the correct evidence to prove this wrong  or right please let all our brothers and sisters know it.

Jazaakallahu Khair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the sunnah that proves that talking while eating is Haram or anything else.  On the other hand there are narrations which prove otherwise, where sometimes the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) spoke while eating.  Like the time some meat was brought to him, he took a bite out of it the he [said](https://sunnah.com/muslim:194a):

> أَنَا سَيِّدُ النَّاسِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ...
>
> I shall be the leader of mankind on the Day of Resurrection...

For further information see [this (Arabic)](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/142516).

Answer (score 0):

> Muslim (2052) it is narrated from Jabir ibn ‘Abdullah that the Prophet (ﷺ) asked his family for condiments and they said: 'We do not have anything but vinegar.' He called for it and he started eating it [while] saying: “*What a good condiment vinegar is, what a good condiment vinegar is.*”

Al-Nawawi commented the narration: "This shows that it is *mustahabb* to talk whilst eating, so as to put the diners at ease. Sharh Sahih Muslim (14/7)